# is there a way to pull from Git using HTTP with a deployment key

Tags: git

I was wondering if there is a way to pull from a git repo using HTTP and a deployment key(or anything that doesn't involve plainText). 
There is no way to access ssh as it is blocked (don't ask :P ), so it appears my options are limited to using HTTP for my origin.

If I can't use a Deployment key, what would be the next best option?

I'll be using web hooks to tell me when an repo is updated, but I'd rather have it trigger a script that leverage's something that is **not** plain text; 
ie: http_username: plainText
    http_password: plainText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP is, by definition, plain text. Git does not implement its own encryption. If you don't want to use plain text, you must use HTTPS or SSH. If HTTPS is blocked (strange), then SSH is almost certainly blocked (common). However, in the off chance it is open, GitHub has some excellent documentation surrounding this.

https://developer.github.com/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#deploy-keys

Comment: Yes https and SSH is blocked (I know.. it's silly but I can't control the server), however generating a oAuth token seems like the only bet I have and trying to get them to at least enable https. Thanks for the reply